# jQuery - Having trouble triggering a click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think this should be an easy one but it's been confusing me for a few hours.  I kinds of get why it doesn't work, but at the same time I don't.

So..

**This sets the first thumbs rel value**

```
var firstThumb = "01"
```

**This is using the firstThumb variable to get the first thumb by its rel attr**

```
var getThumb   = $('#thumbs a').attr('rel' + firstThumb);
```

I've set "firstThumb" as a variable as I intend to increase it after each triggered click so it goes on to 02, 03, 04 etc....  For anybody wondering why I've done it that way.

So the result of getThumb SHOULD be

```
$('#thumbs a').attr('rel', '01');
```

unless I've done something wrong?

NOW, once I've retrieved this - I want to click the #thumb a with a rel attribute of 01

I've been playing around for a while and I keep coming back to this:

```
getThumb.trigger("click");
```

This is essentially

```
$('#thumbs a').attr('rel', '01').trigger("click);
```

Can anybody see what I've done wrong here, as I say it's probably quite simple but I'm new to jQuery and I'm struggling :)

Full set of above code with interval

```
var firstThumb = "01"
var getThumb   = $('#thumbs a').attr('rel' + firstThumb);

setInterval(function(){
   getThumb.trigger("click");
   thumbIncrease;
}, 1000);
```

For clarity, thumbIncrease is a function I've not written yet that after the first triggered click, the firstThumb variable is increased by 1, so it clicks the next thumbnail.

Thanks for any help!

**I've fiddled it here if it helps:**

http://jsfiddle.net/w235svyL/1/

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#thumbs a').attr('rel' + firstThumb);
```

returns the value of attribute which matches `'rel' + firstThumb`

To access the element, you should use

```
$('#thumbs a[rel="'+firstThumb+'"]');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!!  Thanks TJ!  I tried something similar to this, but I couldn't figure it out.  Really appreciate it!